# hWnd for each XL proc; each proc is at the top of the Z-order

Tags: vba, com, excel

This successively activates every XL process that happens to be running:

```
    Public Sub Test()
     Dim varAry()
     Dim iInstances As Long
     Dim hWndDesk As Long
     Dim hWndXL As Long
     Dim x As Long
     Dim var As Variant

     On Error Resume Next

    '---
     hWndDesk = GetDesktopWindow

     Do
      iInstances = iInstances + 1
      hWndXL = FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow, hWndXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)

      If hWndXL <> 0 Then
       ReDim Preserve varAry(iInstances)
    'Get the next Excel window
       varAry(iInstances) = hWndXL
      Else
       Exit Do
      End If
     Loop

    '---
     For x = 1 To UBound(varAry)
      MsgBox varAry(x)
      var = SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd:=varAry(x), BOOL:=False)
     Next x
exit_Sub
    End Sub
```

But a GetObject() can't be applied successively to each of the processes that are activated.  I'd like to use such an object to count the number of workbooks that are open under each process.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to that. I had prepped it and submitted it earlier in the day but later noticed it hadn't posted. When I reopened it to try it again I didn't notice that the final edits weren't there.  (Was wondering why it was being downvoted so much.)

Comment: "If multiple instances of the application you want to automate are running, there is no way to guarantee which instance the GetObject function will return." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164798(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: The Running Object Table might be what you're after, but I've never found a way to access it from VB/VBA.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. What about AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IDispatch, ppvObject)?  Any possibilities there?

Comment: The code above brings a window to the top and also obtains its hWnd. (Albeit it's not an 'ActiveWindow' according to return values in my VBA routine--even tho' the caption bar is solid blue.) Because AccessibleObjectFromWindow() would seem to get the ball rolling from there, I'm experimenting with the function, but don't know enough about marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will calculate the number of "Parent" classes that are found.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow( _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                      ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                      ByVal lclassName As String, _
                      ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim handleCount As Integer
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr
        'ConsoleWindowClass is for "Command Prompt" / cmd.exe in Windows.
        hWnd = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass", vbNullString)
        If hWnd.ToInt32 <> 0 Then handleCount += 1

        Do
            hWnd = FindWindowEx(0, hWnd, "ConsoleWindowClass", vbNullString)
            If hWnd.ToInt32 <> 0 Then
                handleCount += 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

        MessageBox.Show("Found " & handleCount.ToString() & " handles...", "Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Historically I've always used [Pat or JK's API Spy](http://patorjk.com/downloads/patorjkapispy51.zip) (since '98 or so) to obtain a VBA/6 friendly view of how to get the window handle (generates vb code for you, would recommend editing it though)

[pInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) is a great resource for all Win32 API's such as [FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) and [FindWindowEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html) used in the example above. Check the links for each as they're are extensive examples on how to properly implement the functions.